# Await Block/Promise/Fetch for passing JSON data to Svelte component

Tags: javascript, svelte

The {{#await}} block in Svelte is fairly new at this point so this use case may not be one that can be achieved using this method yet.

I tried to pass a url (location of a JSON file) to a component as a property and pick it up within a promise inside component itself, the benefit being that I can make use of the {{#await}} block to handle the state within the component.

The component is being used within a larger component like so:

```
<Showcase dataUrl="/js/showcase.json" />
```

Within the Showcase component I'm using a Promise as a property (see in Svelte docs [here](https://svelte.technology/guide#await-blocks)) to give the component a state using the {{#await}} block.

```
    export default {
    data() {
        return {
            showcaseData: new Promise(fulfil => fetch(dataUrl)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => ({
                    data: data.assets
                }))
                .then(res => {
                    fulfil(res.data)
                })
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't pick up the `dataUrl` property within the Promise. (Can I?)

The other way I can see as being an option to achieve this behaviour is to wrap a promise in an observer (Rich Harris suggests this [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/654#issuecomment-345514247)). However, it seems a shame not to use an {{#await}} if there is actually a way to access `dataUrl` because this would (in theory) be the most concise way to handle the setting of `showcaseData` when the component loads.

Can anyone see a way that this might be possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `computed` property derived from `dataUrl`:

```html
<script>
  export default {
    computed: {
      showcaseData: showcaseUrl => {
        return fetch(dataUrl)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => data.assets);
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

(Note that since `fetch` already returns a Promise, we don't need to wrap it in a new Promise and call `fulfil`.)

Demo here: https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.56.0&gist=24fc0d0fb6ee9b73c736018ab4a00fe6

Comment: Yeah thanks so much - got it. I did notice that there's an error in the console due to dataUrl being undefined the first time the computed property executes the fetch - so I figured I'd use:

`computed: {
  showcaseData: dataUrl => {
   if (typeof dataUrl === "undefined") {
    return false;
   }
   return fetch(dataUrl)
    .then(...
`
It looks a little hacky I guess but I couldn't figure out a way to prevent the computed property from continuing if dataUrl hadn't been set.

Comment: That's odd, if `dataUrl` is set via a prop from the parent component it should never be undefined (unless the prop itself is undefined, of course)

Comment: Ah. Ermm. I'll keep at it then. Quite likely I've crossed a couple of wires somewhere! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok so this seems to have disappeared. Turns out I still had components being instantiated individually and bundled by Rollup at the main.js entry point which was causing some duplication and confusion I think. Whoops! Have now made use of `<Component />` to conditionally render components if they're needed and have a single App.html to rule them all. Thanks again!